# Google Analytics SDK for Android Isn't Tracking App Usage

Tags: java, android, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm attempting to track the usage of my android app using the following tutorial:

```
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/
```

However my dashboard never appears to show any usage even after installing the application on multiple devices and running it in the emulator.

My implementation is as follows:

### STARTACTIVITY.java

```
public class StartActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.start);
            EasyTracker.getInstance(this).activityStart(this);
```

### ANALYTICS.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:ignore="TypographyDashes">
  <!--Replace placeholder ID with your tracking ID-->
  <string name="ga_trackingId">UA-xxxxxxx-2</string>

  <!--Enable automatic activity tracking-->
  <bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>

  <!--Enable automatic exception tracking-->
  <bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>
</resources>
```

### MANIFEST:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.test.datasettings"
   android:versionCode="4"
    android:versionName="1.3" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_APN_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/notifications_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.test.datasettings.StartActivity"
            android:label="@string/display_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
         <activity
            android:name="com.example.test.datasettings.UpdateActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.test.datasettings.ConfigFinalActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize">
        </activity>
            <activity
            android:name="com.example.test.datasettings.MySSLSocketFactory"
            android:configChanges="orientation">
        </activity>
        <activity 
            android:name="com.example.test.datasettings.NotificationActivityForMultiProf"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

### DASHBOARD:

http://datasettings.site90.net/Capture.PNG

Comment: Can we assume you have the correct tracking id in there and not UA-xxxxxxx-2 ?

Comment: Did you put the line: EasyTracker.getInstance(this).activityStop(this); on the onStop method ?

Comment: Yes - I have the correct tracking ID (not xxxxx)

Comment: No - I did not put EasyTracker.getInstance(this).activityStop(this); in my onStop method (I do not have one - nor do I have onStart - I have it in my onCreate -  should I create an onStop method?)